# Collect values from List of objects to Map

Tags: java

I have class:

```
class Employee {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   //getters/setters
}
```

Also I've an Arraylist with employees:

```
List<Employee> employees = new Arraylist<>();
```

How can I extract `id` as a key and `name` as a value to HashMap (with streams)?

`map.put(employee.getId(), employee.getName())`

**UPDATED**

What if I've a custom Lists as fields?

```
class Employee {
   private List<Filters> filters;
   private String name;
   //getters/setters
}

class Filter {
   String name;
   String keyword;
   //getters/setters
}
```

And I want to put `name` (from Filter) as a value, and `keyword` as a key to map.

Comment: which name though? The one from `Employee` or the one from `Filter`?

Comment: name from Filter

Comment: You could use `employees.stream().flatMap(e -> e.getFilters().stream()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Filter::getName, Filter::getKeyword));`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert using streams as below:

```
 public Map<Integer, String> convertListToMap(List<Employee> list) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = list.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Employee:: getName));
    return map;
}
```

Comment: You can return the stream result directly, no need to store into useless map variable.

Comment: Updated my question, any tips?

Answer (score -2):

```html
Map<String,String> map=Maps.newHashMap();
employees.stream().forEach(->{
  map.put(i.getId,i.getName);
});
```

Comment: `Collectors.toMap` is more elegant.

Comment: Doesn't even compile, also why use `Maps.newHashMap()` instead of `new HashMap<>()`?